# Transfering data between multiple scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, volume

I am new to C# and Unity and I tried to implement a volume slider. I can now adjust the volume, but the volume resets every time I try to load a new scene.

Could someone tell me how to transfer the volume to other scenes? I am using Unity 2018.3.14f1 and the code I am using for the volume is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class SetVolume : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer mixer;

    public void SetLevel(float sliderValue)
    {
        mixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) * 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: check [dontDrestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) to maintain objects across your scenes

Comment: hmmm, I thought DontDestroyOnLoad() was no longer suggested, but I can't find that in the docs now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save It in `PlayerPrefs`, Then load it on Start or anywhere you need it.

```
public class SetVolume : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer mixer;
     
    
    void Start()
    {
        SetLevel(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MusicVol"));
    }

    public void SetLevel(float sliderValue)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MusicVol", sliderValue);
        mixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) * 20);
    }
}
```